# Radix sort with 2 digit elements

Tags: algorithms, radix-sort

How can we prove that radix sort correctly sorts an array of 2 elements with 2 digits each ?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  What research have you done?  Where have you looked?  Have you tried working through some examples, looking for patterns, forming a hypothesis, and trying to prove it?  Which variety of Radix sort are you referring to?  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort.)  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for suggestions on how to improve your question.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new here. Thanks for the welcome. I will improve the way I ask. I am talking about Most Significant digit Radix sort